# What does "leave the pigs alone" mean

Tags: word-meaning

This is from a talk on agile teams/enterprises at Microsoft Academy:

> Embrace chicken-ness
>   - Leaving the pigs alone is a tough job, but somebody’s got to do it

The slide is about how to not manage a team, so I guess it means **to keep your hands off** but I couldn't find anything on the web so I'm wondering if there is an additional notion and where this comes from.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicken_and_the_Pig section on "Agile project management"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the comments (@Tromano, consider making it an answer, since it is): [chicken and pig fable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicken_and_the_Pig).

```
A Pig and a Chicken are walking down the road.
The Chicken says: "Hey Pig, I was thinking we should open a restaurant!"
Pig replies: "Hm, maybe, what would we call it?"
The Chicken responds: "How about 'ham-n-eggs'?"
The Pig thinks for a moment and says: "No thanks. I'd be committed, but you'd only be      involved!"
```

The etymology is unknown to me, but the chicken would be a non-committing part of a team (managing the work for instance), while the pig would be fully committed (doing all the actual work).